# onclick doesn't add (or remove) a class to the clicked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/HMkcD/1/

It contains a series of colored blocks (divs), click the 1 to see the blocks. The HTML produced looks like this:

```
<div id="plane">
<div class="tile tile1" block-id="1" style-id="1" style="left:0px; top:0px"></div>
<div class="tile tile2" block-id="2" style-id="2" style="left:100px; top:0px"></div>
<div class="tile tile1" block-id="3" style-id="1" style="left:200px; top:0px"></div>
<div class="tile tile2" block-id="4" style-id="2" style="left:0px; top:100px"></div>
<div class="tile tile1" block-id="5" style-id="1" style="left:100px; top:100px"></div>
<div class="tile tile2" block-id="6" style-id="2" style="left:200px; top:100px"></div>
<div class="tile tile1" block-id="7" style-id="1" style="left:0px; top:200px"></div>
<div class="tile tile2" block-id="8" style-id="2" style="left:100px; top:200px"></div>
<div class="tile tile1" block-id="9" style-id="1" style="left:200px; top:200px"></div>
<div class="tile tile3" block-id="10" style-id="3" style="left:50px; top:50px"></div><div class="tile tile4" block-id="11" style-id="4" style="left:150px; top:50px"></div>
<div class="tile tile4" block-id="12" style-id="4" style="left:50px; top:150px"></div>
<div class="tile tile3" block-id="13" style-id="3" style="left:150px; top:150px"></div>
</div>
```

I want to add a class `ss` to a colored block/div when I click a block; this clicked block becomes the selected block. Then I want to click to select another block. If the style-id's of these 2 blocks are the same, I want to remove those blocks. If not, then remove the `ss` class again.

I've created the following code to do this:

```
$('#plane').click(function(){                            //the click function
    var clickedBlock = $(this);                          //get the data of the clicked div/block
    clickedBlock.addClass('ss');                         //add class ss to the clicked div/block
    if (blockSelected) {                                 //if div/block is selected
       if ($(blockSelected).attr('block-id') == clickedBlock.attr('block-id')) {  //if block-id of the selected div equals the block-id of the clicked div
           clickedBlock.removeClass('ss');               //remove class ss
       } else {                                          //else
          if ($(blockSelected).attr('style-id') == clickedBlock.attr('style-id')) { //if style selected div equals style clicked div
              $(blockSelected).addClass('x');            //ad class x to selected div or better: remove div
              clickedBlock.addClass('x');                //ad class x to clicked div or better: remove div
              totalTiles = totalTiles - 2;               //deduct 2 of the total tiles
               } else {                                  //if not equal styles
              $(blockSelected).removeClass('ss');        //remove class ss form the selected div
              clickedBlock.removeClass('ss');            //remove class ss from the clicked div
           }
        }
        blockSelected = null;
   } else {
        blockSelected = this;
   }
});
```

The problem is, I can't get it to work. I think `#plane` at the start isn't right either, but I am not sure what code to put there since `#plane div` doesn't seem to work.

Thank you!

Comment: try `$(document).on('click', '.tile', function() {` instead of `$('#plane').click(function(){`

Comment: Here's a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/TzBdYRabfdzOivPW4bAe?p=preview) of what @RodrigoAssis suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have it doing what you want.

I changed your fiddle. Right after you create the HTML of the `plane` by using `el.innerHTML = html.join('');` I added this:

```
         $(el).find('.tile').click(function () {
                //get the data of the clicked div/block
                var clickedBlock = $(this); 
                //add class ss to the clicked div/block
                clickedBlock.addClass('ss'); 
                if (blockSelected) { 
                    //if div/block is selected
                    if ($(blockSelected).attr('block-id') == clickedBlock.attr('block-id')) { 
                        //if block-id of the selected div equals the block-id of the clicked div
                        //remove class ss
                        clickedBlock.removeClass('ss'); 
                    } else { //else
                        if ($(blockSelected).attr('style-id') == clickedBlock.attr('style-id')) { 
                            //if style selected div equals style clicked div
                            //ad class x to selected div or better: remove div
                            $(blockSelected).remove(); 
                            //ad class x to clicked div or better: remove div
                            clickedBlock.remove(); 
                            //deduct 2 of the total tiles
                            totalTiles = totalTiles - 2; 
                        } else { //if not equal styles
                            //remove class ss form the selected div
                            $(blockSelected).removeClass('ss'); 
                            //remove class ss from the clicked div
                            clickedBlock.removeClass('ss'); 
                        }
                    }
                    blockSelected = null;
                } else {
                    blockSelected = this;
                }
            });
```

Now when you click two blocks with the same sytle-id they are removed. When you click the first block and then a non matching block, the styles are removed.

[I think that is what you wanted](http://jsfiddle.net/93hhN/2/).

Comment: Thank you Pow-Ian, I see I had a view errors in my code, your given excample is very helpfull. Do you happen to have a tip vor getting the: `var totalBlocks = 0; // count the blocks OR (easier) get the highest block_id` (in this cause is should be 13). Thanks again

Comment: I had replaced `totalBlocks` with `totalTiles` because it did not appear that you were using it. If you add it back to the script and then assign it right after the click handler like this: `totalBlocks = $('.tile').length` the jQuery object is going to contain an array of all the 'tile' class elements. So by taking its count, you have the amount of 'tile' elements in use. This is true through the life of the script. At anypoint you can check the count that way and get the accurate amount of 'tile' elements.

Comment: Thanks Pow-Ian for the reply, I will give it a shot and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

OP,

Using the `on()` method that @Rodrigo Assis suggested is half the battle. In short, you were trying to attach listeners to elements that are created post DOM load — for this, you can't used direct events, instead you need to used delegated events. The old method was `live()`, which has since been deprecated. `on()` is the new standard. More on that [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As for the logic you described, I reworked your code a bit, and optimized it. I'm pretty sure this achieves what you ask, with more condensed logic. Below is the rundown, [here is the updated Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/9KGLCnnGkybc6bCXJpNR?p=preview)

### JS

```
 ...
    var pairs = [];
    $('#plane').on('click', '.tile', function () { 
        $(this).addClass('ss');
        pairs.push($(this));
        if (pairs.length == 2) {
             if ($(pairs[0]).attr('style-id') === $(pairs[1]).attr('style-id') && $(pairs[0]).attr('block-id') != $(pairs[1]).attr('block-id')) {
                $(pairs[0]).remove();
                $(pairs[1]).remove();
                pairs = [];
            } else {
                $(pairs[0]).removeClass('ss');
                $(pairs[1]).removeClass('ss');
                pairs = [];
            }
        }
    });
 ...
```

### Brief

What we want is to basically say:

- User clicks blockA, highlight it
- User clicks blockB, highlight it

  - if blocks have same style-id, remove them
  - otherwise, unhighlight both of them

In this case, the `pairs` array is your friend.

Oh, one other thing — your original code had this: `totalTiles = totalTiles - 2`. I'd suggest mapping `totalTiles` as a reference to `$('.tile').length`. I looked through your code, but couldn't seem to figure out why you were decrementing its value.

Hope it helps.

-EDIT-

Updated conditional on [line 185 of app.js](http://plnkr.co/edit/9KGLCnnGkybc6bCXJpNR?p=preview) to make sure if the *same* block is selected twice, it's not treated as a pair. Fiddle and code gist above fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply couzzi. I was not aware of the pairs option. It looks very interesting. Going to do some more research on this and I am thinking to implement it. About the `totalTiles = totalTiles - 2`, I've made a typo and should be: `totalBlocks = totalBlocks - 2`, so that the: `var totalBlocks = 0; // count the blocks OR (easier) get the highest block_id` (in this cause is should be 13) can be used. The goal of this is to make a game and I need this to count the blocks. If it's 0 then the game is over. Do you have any tips to get the max number of blocks? Thanks again

Comment: Oh, an extra point. Using Pairs I can remove the `block_id` part (which is cool, I don't use it for anything else). Only when doing so, I cannot use the highest `block_id` anymore and the blocks need to be counted. How to do this?

Comment: Hmm, counting the blocks should be as easy as `var blockCount = $('.tile').length`. If you want to limit the scope of the count, be more specific with your selector: `$('some-parent-el .tile').length` I know you had two different games in the demo. 

For the highest `block_id`, I'd loop over the returned `blockCount` array with `each()`, and pull out `$(this).attr('block_id')`, push those values into a new array, `join()` it, and then use `Math.max()` to return the highest number. Might be a *little* more to it than that, but that's the gist.

Comment: Hi couzzi, I've found a small bug. When I click a block it gets selected. If I click it again, the block is removed, which shouldn't happen. It's not a pair (unless it pairs with itself, code wise) and it should be deselected instead of removed. Kind regards

Comment: @Maurice - Fixed and updated. New check is: `if ($(pairs[0]).attr('style-id') === $(pairs[1]).attr('style-id') && $(pairs[0]).attr('block-id') != $(pairs[1]).attr('block-id'))`. Also, thought you selected another answer?

Comment: yes I did, but I find the pairs solution (which is new to me) very interesting too. Atm I am playing around with it a bit. If I end up using it in the final code I'll change the answer to this answer as accepted (only seems fair)

Comment: Gotcha. Also, 'pairs' is just what I named the `array()`, you could name it 'bananas' if you wanted. Just fyi.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a completely different approach, then consider this :

```
var BLOCK_PAIR = (function() {//Singleton NAMESPACE pattern.
    //Private vars
    var blocks = $(),
        delay = 500,
        selClss = 'ss',
        compareAttr = 'style-id',
        disabled = false;

    //Private functions
    var select = function(e) {
        var $b = $(e.target);
        if(disabled) return;
        if( blocks.length == 1 && blocks.not($b).length == 0 ) {
            reset();//allow first block to be deselected
            return;
        }
        if( blocks.length >= 2 ) reset(); //should never happen
        blocks = blocks.add($b.addClass(selClss));
        compare();
    };
    var compare = function() {
        if(blocks.length == 2) {
            if(blocks.eq(0).attr(compareAttr) == blocks.eq(1).attr(compareAttr)) {
                setTimeout(remove, delay);
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(reset, delay);
            }
            disabled = true;//inhibit block selection during timeout delay.
        }
    };
    var remove = function() {
        blocks.remove();
        reset();
    };
    var reset = function() {
        blocks.removeClass(selClss);
        blocks = $();
        disabled = false;
    };

    //Expose private functions as public methods
    return {
        select: select,
    };
})();

$(function() {
    $('#plane').on('click', '.tile', BLOCK_PAIR.select);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5NyJw/

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. It's good to know there are other ways to do this

Comment: When you have time, follow the code through. Maintaining the user selections as a jQuery collection makes for an interesting solution.